# HTTPS domain shows blank page while HTTP works fine

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, iis, https

When I navigate to my domain link: https://www.mdxbusiness.com I see a blank page with no errors.
I have to note that before I forwarded the HTTP to HTTPS the http://www.mdxbusiness.com worked fine.

I have:

- `GoDaddy` domain with a valid `SSL Certificate`.
- `AWS EC2` 2 instances associated to `Elastic Load Balancer` with `HTTP & HTTPS` Listeners (and security groups).
- CName in `GoDaddy` that links to the `AWS Elastic Load Balancer`.
- In both `AWS EC2` instances I have an `RDP` with `IIS` with a binding to `HTTP & HTTPS` - The `HTTPS` has the `SSL Certificate` of the `GoDaddy's` domain.
- I use `Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Base` in both `AWS EC2` instances, I have their the `DB` which is the `SQL SERVER` and the project which is `MVC`.

Again - The `HTTP` worked good as expected but the `HTTPS` not - shows a blank page.

What could be the cause for this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ELB listeners should match below setting. The HTTPS should listen to Port 80 [image]